# How can I find unique values in an array and assign them to variables in ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

How can I find unique values in an array.

For instance:

```
my_array = [2,4,4,5,5,7]
```

In the above array are two unique values 2 and 7 and I would like to know either a self defined or other method to assign these unique values to variables.

Comment: running count on the array every time will be super slow if you're working with a large array, as it grows with O(n^2)

Comment: `arr.uniq.select { |n| arr.count(n) == 1 }` would be an improvement to my earlier suggestion, though still not as performant as the answers given so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `array.group_by`.

```
my_array.group_by{|v| v}.delete_if{|k,v| v.length > 1}.keys
```

or alternatively

```
  my_array.group_by{|v| v}.select{|k,v| v.length == 1}.keys
```

Comment: not sure why this is being downvoted. I just benchmarked it with a 2 million element array and it seems relatively performant, and correct.

Comment: Have you got the benchmark results? It would be good to be able to compare all the methods.

Comment: I just generated an array in irb with 2 million elements, called shuffle, then called Benchmark.measure. The each with object measure was about 1.14s real time vs group_by at 1.66s

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit leggy, perhaps, but gets the job done

```
my_array.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)){|x,h| h[x] += 1}.select{|k,v| v == 1}.keys
```

Comment: This returns an array with the unique values of the original array. Is it in terms of result in anyway different to or better then `myarray.select { |n| myarray.count(n) == 1 }`? I'm assuming it might be faster?

Comment: much faster. myarray.count will hang on huge shuffled arrays.

Comment: which of these two answers is faster and better practice?

Comment: Id say Davids is slightly faster, but mine is a bit more readable. If you need performance, go with davids, readability, mine.